# How to configure chrome and firefox to open Gmail when user clicks on an HTML mailto:joe@doe.com

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, email, android, gmail

I would like to know whether it is possible to configure Chrome and Firefox to open Gmail when the user clicks on an HTML `<a href="mailto:joe@doe.com">click to send me e-mail</a>`. Currently, my Windows 7 OS tends to open the (IMHO nowadays pretty useless) MS Outlook application, but I would like to open a Gmail browser session instead (or launch the Android Gmail app when the link is clicked on my Chrome for Android or Firefox for Android).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a browser extension. I personally use "mailto:" by Famlam under Safari: https://code.google.com/p/mailto-chromeextension/

Chrome version here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gppbppehiogfokmpligejhaepeopajdf

Firefox shouldn't require a browser extension, try the following steps:

1. Click the menu button and choose Preferences.
2. Select the Applications panel.
3. Search for the Content-type: mailto and select it.
4. Click on the Actions column in the mailto row, to change the action.
5. Select Use Gmail and you're done.